# How do I export animations with Geo Nodes?

Tags: animation

So I've made a geo node that makes a venom like monster with tendrils and I want to import the animations into unreal engine five. However when I export the animation as an fbx its just the first frame of the monster sliding across the ground with none of the procedural effect. How do I make the effects of the geo node show in the animation?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: I know you can export geometry node animations as allembic files and then import into Unreal. There are a few existing questions around this on stack exchange.

Comment: mesh deformations outside of shape keys and bone deformations, most of the time you won't have options other than alembic or USD. These are all very standard formats in the movies and VFX industries, but not so much in video games. Unreal Engine does support it, but it remains pretty basic. The best solution for game engines remains to stick to assets that can be done with bones and shapekeys as much as possible.